# Mobile App executes html scripts

Tags: html, xss, hybrid-mobile-app

Am testing a mobile app, in one of scenario where there is option to enter text. I have inputted html code say something below and can submit it

Below codes are executed on my mobile app

```
enter code here
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Result: Shows the input and button controls, however button click doesn't show alert

OR

```
enter code here
<form action="http://google.com" method="get">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
</form>
```

Result: Shows up input and button click opens targeted external page in the app.

OR

```
enter code here
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="username" value="admin" />
<input name="password" type="password" value="secret" />
<input name="injected" value="injected" dirname="password" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I can even embed a youtube video and play it in app. 
1.What kind of security threat is it. 
2.To What extent does it harm app security. 
3.Does it fall under XSS. Any example scripts to pull app info or alert popup would be helpful

Comment: You have to show us the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, i haven't used code format while posting. Updated post with code snippets. Please let me know your inputs. thanks

Comment: Any inputs here will be helpful.TIA